# Magical Record save in background

Tags: ios, xcode, multithreading, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using the Magical Record framework to save user settings. Now, for the first time, I want to save things in a background thread. On Magical Record's github page is an example snippet I don't fully understand:

```
Person *person = ...;
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){

    Person *localPerson = [person MR_inContext:localContext];

    localPerson.firstName = @"John";
    localPerson.lastName = @"Appleseed";

}];
```

Why is the first line needed? Can't I just completely create the Person in the block? Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Of course you can. This example just grabs a `person` object from the outer context (your default one or whatever) and gives you a pointer to it in the `localContext` so you can update it in the background. If you were to create a `person` from scratch you could do something like this:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){

    Person *localPerson = [Person MR_createInContext:localContext];

    localPerson.firstName = @"John";
    localPerson.lastName = @"Appleseed";

}];
```

And you're done.

PS. Note that `MR_createInContext:` is a class method called on `Person` class (instead of `MR_inContext:` instance method which is called on `person` instance).

Comment: As I see, the method I wrote above seems to be deprecated, what method should I use to save in the background? There are a couple of "new" methods listed, but none of them has "background" in its name.

Comment: @LinusAn It depends on the version of MagicalRecord that you use. You can check their [github repo here](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) (I believe `saveWithBlock:` is the analogous method in v3.x)

Comment: Ah thank you very much! Then I'll use that one. I didn't know v3 was out yet, I better get the newest version.

Comment: Hmm weird console log when I use saveWithBlock: -[NSManagedObjectContext(MagicalSaves) MR_saveWithOptions:completion:](0x1f091a00) NO CHANGES IN ** UNNAMED ** CONTEXT - NOT SAVING

Comment: But I wrote something inside the block which should be saved?

Comment: Are you sure that you've created your entity like this: `[Person MR_createInContext:localContext];` inside the block ? (Also, sorry for the v3.x thing, this is the next major version to be released. Current  stable one is 2.1)

Comment: I just found out that I had to use "User *theUser = [activeUser MR_inContext:localContext]; ", then it worked. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create the Person also in the block. The inContext: method is only necessary if you fetch for example a Person from a different context.
Beware, if you create the Person in the block, then you should use the createInContext: method.

Answer (score 0):

Magical Record save and fetch are Context-Based. So, You can either create a record in the default context or create record in a new context using MR_createInContext method. But, while fetching the records, the context should be the same as you created.

http://pthiaga.blogspot.in/2014/11/running-database-fetch-core-data-in.html