# Use saved item in save completion Magical Record

Tags: core-data, objective-c-blocks, magicalrecord, magicalrecord-2.2

I would like to use the item that has been just been saved in the completion block of Magical Record saveWithBlock method. For example:

```
//Get the ID of an existing NSManagedObject to use in the save block (if it exists)
NSManagedObjectID *objectRef = [self.object objectID];

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    //This method either loads an existing object and makes changes or creates  a new entity in localContext
   NSManagedObject *itemToSave = [self prepareItemInContext:localContext WithID: objectRef];
 } completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
     if (success) {
          //here I want to get at the object 'itemToSave' that was either created in the save block (with a new objectID) or updated (with the ID objectRef)
```

Comment: why don't u try with associated objects....
or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459321/magical-record-save-in-background?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to have a reference to your external context to load the object with that ID:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *outsideContext = //...
NSManagedObjectID *objectID = //...

[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext) {

} completion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {

    NSManagedObject *newlySavedObject = [outsideContext existingObjectWithID:objectID];
    //...do stuff here
}];
```

Generally, however, I would discourage this usage. I would instead recommend keeping any predicates or means of reloading your data set handy, and dump and refetch fresh data from the store. This will give you proper object references. Another, more precise way of updating objects in other contexts is to listen to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification` and merge this updates into your context. From there, your data will be "refreshed" and as long as you're KVO'ing a property, or using a `NSFetchedResultsController` with a delegate, your updates will propagate to the UI (or other destination).

Comment: I found that this would fail for items that have not been previously saved. CoreData can change the objectID when it saves to temporary storage. For me, the objectID.isTemporary is YES.

Answer (score 0):

Either just use `self.object` or, if you create a new object and insert it (presumably because `objectRef` is nil) then you should get the corresponding new object from the main thread context and use that.

How you do that shuffle is the interesting part. It isn't exactly clear why you're using a background context at the moment so you can also consider changing that, which removes all of the complexity.

If you need to keep the background context then you need to decide on how to get that data back to the main thread. Generally, you could use `performBlockAndWait:` inside your current block to get the new object from the main context and then store it into a property on your class so you can use it in the completion block. This would be setting the `self.object` property.

Comment: Previously everything was handled using self.object, but it is my understanding that you should not pass NSManagedObjects around, as they are not thread safe. Instead I pass the ObjectID over the block boundary. I was also trying to avoid just saving everything on the main context as it seems safer/cleaner to only save the small number of objects I know I've created to the local context rather than any that have been created in the global default context.

Comment: Correct, only ever pass the id between threads. I've edited the answer slightly. You pass the id to your current block and update or create. If you create then in a nested block you get the new object on the main thread and store it so you can use it in the completion block.